# Empty and append expanding height of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running this code:

```
$('#storeTable').empty();

$('#storeTable').append("<tr>");
$('#storeTable').append("<td>");
$('#storeTable').append(returnData["1"]["ID"]);
$('#storeTable').append("</td>");
$('#storeTable').append("</tr>");
```

However if I run it multiple times in one page load, the 'storeTable' element gets taller and taller with every run. Am I missing something obvious, is this a gotcha of jQuery/JavaScript, is it the fault of my browser (Chrome), or am I doing something wrong?

The code obviously needs refining, I'm just trying to get a bare-bones implementation of a dynamic section of a page.

If you'd like any other details, please ask, rather than just downvoting without a comment.

storeTable is, of course, a table, too.

Comment: `.append` appends elements, not raw html. try concatenating your html into a string and the append the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.append()` to append partial pieces of HTML.  .`append()` only appends whole formed objects and when it appends them it appends them as the last child of the target object.

To add to that, some browsers are picking about how you can or cannot create/remove content in tables.

Assuming `#storeTable` is the `<table>` tag, you could assign `.html()` to create a whole new table all at once:

```
$("#storeTable").html("<tr><td>" + returnData["1"]["ID"] + "</td></tr>");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5BVdX/

Comment: Using .html worked perfectly, and +1 for also covering the emptying. Not sure why I hadn't thought of trying this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#storeTable').empty();

// Will create three rows, one after another
$('#storeTable').append("<tr><td>123</td></tr>");
$('#storeTable').append("<tr><td>456</td></tr>");
$('#storeTable').append("<tr><td>789</td></tr>");

// Will create three rows, each next replaces previous
$('#storeTable').html("<tr><td>123</td></tr>");
$('#storeTable').html("<tr><td>456</td></tr>");
$('#storeTable').html("<tr><td>789</td></tr>");
```